# how to convert org.w3c.dom.Document to org.jdom.Document

Tags: dom, w3c, jdom, jtidy

I need to convert a `org.w3c.dom.Document` to  `org.jdom.Document`

I have tried the following following..

```
InputStream inputStream =  new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());

Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setMakeClean(false);
tidy.setShowWarnings(true); //tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
tidy.setTidyMark(false);
tidy.setNumEntities(true);
tidy.setQuoteAmpersand(true);
tidy.setQuoteMarks(true);
tidy.setQuoteNbsp(false);
tidy.setHideEndTags(false);
tidy.setDropEmptyParas(false);

Document tidyDOM =tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, null);
DOMBuilder domBuilder = new DOMBuilder();
org.jdom.Document jdomDoc = domBuilder.build(tidyDOM);
```

`domBuilder.build(tidyDOM)` throws the following exception:

```
org.jdom.IllegalNameException: The name "html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"" is not legal for JDOM/XML DocTypes: XML names cannot contain the character " ".
    at org.jdom.DocType.setElementName(DocType.java:171)
    at org.jdom.DocType.<init>(DocType.java:111)
    at org.jdom.DocType.<init>(DocType.java:144)
    at org.jdom.DefaultJDOMFactory.docType(DefaultJDOMFactory.java:118)
    at org.jdom.input.DOMBuilder.buildTree(DOMBuilder.java:332)
    at org.jdom.input.DOMBuilder.buildTree(DOMBuilder.java:170)
    at org.jdom.input.DOMBuilder.build(DOMBuilder.java:135)
    at test.JaxenTest.testParsingVisitor(JaxenTest.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if JTidy is creating a malformed DocType node. I suggest using a different HTML parser.

I recommend [The Validator.nu HTML Parser](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/) but there are plenty of others.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two settings and everything should work.

```
tidy.setXHTML(true);
tidy.setDocType("omit");
```

The first setting tells jTidy to output an XHTML file. An XHTML file is valid XML.

The second tab tells tidy not to output a DOCTYPE line into the code.  For some reason JDom does not seem to recognize legitimate html/xhtml doctypes.

Comment: In fairness, this is not a JDOM problem. I think you will find that the DOM Document 'feeding' JDOM is inaccurate... you cannot have an element called: "html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""